# Can I reset volume?

Tags: java, android, service, manifest, volume

I am muting my app using the following code:

```
          AudioManager mAudioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        userVolume = mAudioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM);


        AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0, 0);
        Toast.makeText(Main_Menu.this, "MUTED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

The thing is, I want to be able to **unmute** the app to the same volume that the user was **originally** on. Right now, I can only control the volume to reset the user to:

```
   AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 4, 4);
        Toast.makeText(Main_Menu.this, "UNMUTED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

I saw somewhere to get the volume at the start, and then use that value later to reset. This cannot work for me, since user is constantly switching back to the activity, and I cant have that one-time variable reset.

Is there any way to reset the users volume to what it was before I changed it through my app?

Thanks,

```
{Rich}
```

Comment: Store the volume in SharedPreferences.

Answer (score 0):

```
    AudioManager mAudioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

    userVolume = mAudioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM);


    AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0, 0);
    Toast.makeText(Main_Menu.this, "MUTED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

you have already done what you need just do the following modifications in your above code..

```
    audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,userVolume, 0);
    Toast.makeText(Main_Menu.this, "MUTED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); //user volume you will get by getStreamVolume()
```

Comment: For some reason, this isn't working... Probably because userVolume is getting reset or something... Any other ideas? THanks!

Comment: Also, why is it above the muted toast, shouldnt it be above the unmuted toast?

Comment: yes it should be UNMUTED toast.. have you tried printing the value of userVolume...and how it is getting reset.?

Comment: I think it gets reset every time that activity starts

Comment: USERVOLUME is always the middle now